# Using NTLMSSP authentication for Single Sign On, post data lost (not everytime)

Tags: apache2, http-post, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, kerberos

I have the following AJAX function that I call to send post request to a web server running in Python, using Cherrypy, which runs behind Apache:

```
oAjax.open("POST", "/", true);
oAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
oAjax.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
oAjax.send(parameters);
```

The parameters are being sent as follows:

```
"id=pagename&action=pageaction"
```

Every now and then, I get empty post data when a request is sent.  This does not seem to be consistent.

Using WireShark, we get the following details for a bad request:

```
HTTP    543 POST /? HTTP/1.1 , NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
```

In these cases, we seem to have 0 content length, so our post data seems to have been removed.

It appears to be trying to re-authorize the session when not required, causing the post data to be lost.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

This does not occur in FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the information found on this website, I was able to solve the problem:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251404